# Unmatched ( in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am getting the error:

`Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE`

My code is as follows:

```
if ($entire_line =~ /(\()[^\+\-\*\/]*(\))/){
    $entire_line =~ s/$1//;
    $entire_line =~ s/$2//;
}
```

`$entire_line` might look something like this:

`print ( factor0 ) * (factor1) * factor2, " a b c d"`

I'm trying to remove `()` if they do not contain a numerical operator `+ - / *`.

Result: `print  factor0  * factor1 * factor2, " a b c d"`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: group 1 contains `(` and group 2 contains `)` , see http://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/7

Comment: @AvinashRaj I thought this was what I needed, so I could replace group 1 and 2 with an empty string. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: yep, just capture the inner part and replace all the matched chars with `$2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, just capture the inner part and replace the matched characters with the chars which are present inside the group index 2.

Regex:

```
(\()([^\+\-\*\/]*)(\))
```

Replacement string:

```
$2
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/8)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/(\()([^\+\-\*\/]*)(\))/$2/g;
    print $line;;
}

__DATA__
print ( factor0 ) * (factor1) * factor2, (factor1*factor2) " a b c d"
```

**Output:**

```
print  factor0  * factor1 * factor2, (factor1*factor2) " a b c d"
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash. However, I'm confused with the replacement part. Could you please include the `Perl` code I should use too?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only paranthesis and if the entire line is present in the input file then try this code:(Perl one liner : substitution)

**InputFile:**

```
print ( factor0 ) * (factor1) * factor2, " a b c d" (factor0 + factor1 - factor2)
```

**Code:(Perl One liner)**

```
perl -lne "if($_ =~ s/(\()([^\+\-\*\/]*)(\))/$2/isg) { print $_;} else { print $_;}" Inputfile
```

**Output:**

```
print  factor0  * factor1 * factor2, " a b c d" (factor0 + factor1 - factor2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is probably misguided as there are likely edge cases you're not considering.

However, I would recommend working with balanced parenthesis using [`(?PARNO)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3fPARNO)-(%3f-PARNO)-(%3f%2bPARNO)-(%3fR)-(%3f0)).

The following attempts to strip the balanced parenthesis that do not contain puntuation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

while (<DATA>) {
    simplify_parens($_);
    print;
}

sub simplify_parens {
    s{ \( ( (?: [^()]+ | \( (?1) \) )* ) \) }{
        simplify_parens( my $str = $1 );
        $str =~ m{[*/+-]} ? "($str)" : $str;
    }exg for @_;
}
__DATA__
print ( factor0 ) * (factor1) * factor2, " a b c d"
print ( factor0 ) * (((factor1))) * factor2, " a b c d"
```

Outputs:

```
print  factor0  * factor1 * factor2, " a b c d"
print  factor0  * factor1 * factor2, " a b c d"
```

Well, that's better than the other solutions suggested.

However, what if the data contained expressions like `(((factor1 + factor3)))`?  Shouldn't the outer two sets of parenthesis be stripped and only the last inner one kept?

To achieve that type of functionality, one do something like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

while (<DATA>) {
    simplify_parens($_);
    print;
}

sub simplify_parens {
    my $clean = 1;
    for (@_) {
        my @tokens = split m{ \( ( (?: [^()]+ | \( (?1) \) )* ) \) }x;
        for my $i ( 0 .. $#tokens ) {
            if ( $i % 2 ) {
                $tokens[$i] = "($tokens[$i])" if !simplify_parens( $tokens[$i] );
            } else {
                $clean &&= $tokens[$i] !~ m{[*/+-]};
            }
        }
        $_ = join '', @tokens;
    }
    return $clean;
}

__DATA__
print ( factor0 ) * (factor1) * factor2, " a b c d"
print ( factor0 ) * (((factor1))) * factor2, " a b c d"
print ( factor0 ) * (((factor1 + factor3))) * factor2, " a b c d"
```

Outputs:

```
print  factor0  * factor1 * factor2, " a b c d"
print  factor0  * factor1 * factor2, " a b c d"
print  factor0  * (factor1 + factor3) * factor2, " a b c d"
```

This works a lot better.  Nevertheless, the primary lesson I'd like to communicate is that this is potentially a much bigger and more complicated task than it may first appear.